# Select mininum value after grouping by two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following table contains two grouping variables, `id_point` and `sci_name` and a continuous variable `distance`. There are multiple `distance` values per unique combinations of `id_point` and `sci_name`. I would like to create a table that contains each unique combination between `id_point` and `sci_name` and the minimum `distance` value.

[image]

This was my best attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE sar.test AS
SELECT DISTINCT id_point, sci_name, MIN(distance)
GROUP BY id_point, sci_name,
    FROM sar.dist_mam_na;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GROUP BY goes *after* the FROM, and by definition of aggregation, the groups will be unique so the DISTINCT is irrelevant:

```
SELECT id_point, sci_name, MIN(distance)
FROM sar.dist_mam_na
GROUP BY id_point, sci_name
```